# Apache Mesos to run batch, singleton jobs?

Tags: mesos

We have a lot of batch jobs for our service, executed from one machine, which is now running out of CPU resources.

Most of these jobs are pretty simple. For example, once every 5 minutes, query our database and find data that need to be processed, then process these data, the result is written back to the database.

The trick is that all of these jobs can only be run with one instance at a time, because if two instances running at the same time we will have race conditions and generate duplicate results.

Is Apache Mesos the right solution for us to replace the job server? That is, can we create a lot of small frameworks, each one is a scheduled job, and have Chronos to trigger each of them with a time interval? Can we gurantee that when a job is triggered, only once instance is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Chronos on Mesos would do the trick. To be precise, you don't 'create a lot of small frameworks' but jobs (in Chronos); Chronos being one of the Mesos frameworks, there are many others such as Marathon or [Cook](https://github.com/twosigma/Cook).

The pattern would be as follows (for a containerized job), say in a doc called `test.json`:

```
{
"name": "test",
"cpus": 0.1,
"mem": 100,
"shell": true,
"command": "echo I AM DOING SOME SERIOUS WORK",
"async": false,
"container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "image": "ubuntu:14.04"
},
"schedule": "R/2016-05-23T17:00:00Z/PT1M",
"owner": "michael.hausenblas@dcos.io"
}
```

Now, first you'd register the Chronos job (I'm using [http](http://httpie.org) here but also works with, say, `curl`):

```
$ http POST http://$CHRONOS_NODE:8080/service/chronos/scheduler/iso8601 < test.json
```

The above job would execute from 5pm on today every minute and if you want to you can trigger it manually like so:

```
$ http PUT http://$CHRONOS_NODE:8080/service/chronos/scheduler/job/test
```

Last but not least, Chronos [constraints](http://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/api.html#constraints) allow you to influence placement.

Comment: Just out of interest, how can Chronos avoid the potential "multiple execution problem"? I guess this has to be solved application-wise... AFAIK the constraints cannot solve this.

Comment: I suppose you have a point there, @Tobi, in that constraints alone wouldn't solve OP's issue but I believe in combination with dependent jobs it should work: http://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/api.html#adding-a-dependent-job

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using workflow management / job orchestration tools like [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/) or [Airflow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/). You can define dependencies and have jobs only run after the jobs they depend on have completed.